# Load Multiple pList Files into a View

Tags: swift, plist

I am creating a quiz app and the data are in the pList.

I have multiple pLists representing different categories. I do not want to merge these pList into one single file because I will use them separately for another purpose.

My question is, can we read or load multiple pList files into a View at once? If yes, how?

I am using the following code to load single pList files:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "pListData", ofType: "plist")
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
    pListData = (dict!["Tips"]! as AnyObject) as? Array
```

I am presenting a single data (a question) from a single pList each time a question is loaded. How do you randomly read from multiple pList sources instead of from a single one?

Comment: The answer is yes, you can. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Hello, how can I do it? Its a quiz app so I am presenting a single data from a single pList each time. Can I read randomly from multiple pList sources?

Comment: Aside note: it makes no sense to force cast to AnyObject and then to optionally cast the result as Array. That's not how Optionals should be used.